# Background image in stylesheet not loading Nextjs

Tags: next.js

My root for images is /public/images/MY_IMAGE.JPG

I want to load a background image using CSS.

My code:

```css
.mobile-image-hero-1 {
  background-image: url('/public/images/mobile-image-hero-1.jpg');
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

have also tried `background-image: url('../public/images/mobile-image-hero-1.jpg');`

I'm rendering via class name

`<header className='mobile-image-hero-1 h-48'>`

I just want an easy way to have a div background image.

P.S I have looked at other answers on here to no prevail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images in Next.js in the `public` directory can be referred to with `public` as the base route, so this should work:

```
background-image: url('/images/mobile-image-hero-1.jpg');
```